# how to select elements using xpath

Tags: xpath

This is my `html` code:

```
<div class="loged-in">
<div>
<span> |</span>
<a href="https://www.jabong.com/account/">Hi, abhinav</a>
<span class="drop-arrow"/>
</div>
```

I want to select following link and I have tried this xpath.

```
<a href="https://www.jabong.com/account/">Hi, abhinav</a>
//div[@class='loged-in']/*[1]
```

Comment: No, I want a xpath to select this link using firebug. I already tried the xpath above but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the HTML snippet posted, the target `<a>` element is nested within the outer `<div>` (which currently missing closing tag), so the XPath should've considered the inner `<div>` as well, like so :

```
//div[@class='loged-in']/div/a
```

---

**Demo :** [`xpathtester`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/4893f311e9fdba38ee24b7a03b7f1df9), [`xpatheval`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/4nII258_V)

**Html input :**

```
<div class="loged-in">
<div>
<span> |</span>
<a href="https://www.jabong.com/account/">Hi, abhinav</a>
<span class="drop-arrow"/>
</div>
</div>
```

**Output :**

```
<a href="https://www.jabong.com/account/">Hi, abhinav</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome Browser there's a simple solution you can follow to get XPath of an element however deep the HTML structure is.

1. Inspect your page (Right click -> Inspect)
2. In the `Elements` tab right click on the element which you want to get the XPath for.
3. Select `Copy` -> `Copy XPath` option

Your XPath would be copied to clipboard! Boom!

A Screenshot for your reference!

[image]